# Does using a constant over a standard variable use less memory?

Tags: java, variables, constants

I have done some searching on the internet but fail to find an answer, so I come here hopefully to find it. So my guess would be that it would because say if i declare one `final int foo = 6` it because it wouldn't change in size that it will only be set to what it needs in terms of memory. Where as a variable `int bar = 8` will have to have a larger size in memory because it has a chance later in the program in change.

Comment: An int is an int.  Same size.

Comment: Your guess is not correct.

Comment: The size needed is the same in the two cases, the differences are in the way they are handled by the JVM (and of course what you're allowed to do with it).

Comment: No, no less memory.  But it's often "more correct" to use a final (constant) when you actually don't intend for the value to ever change.

Comment: @OldProgrammer an int is an int is an int....

Comment: @gtgaxiola Except when it's a long, byte or char. :-)

Comment: Discussing this is both entirely meaningless and pointless (meaningless because of compiler optimizations, and pointless because most often it simply doesn't matter performance-wise, be it memory usage or CPU time or… or…)

Comment: For the record, any variable can be `final`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space required for a value depends on the data type, not on the exact value.  Therefore, a

```
final int foo = 6;
```

requires exactly the same space as

```
int bar = 8;
```

or

```
int baz = 0;
```

or

```
int shazam = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

With that in mind, it should not surprise you that whether a variable is declared `final` does not alter its memory requirements.

Answer (score 3):

No a constant uses the exact same memory.

The only difference is that you can't change your constant after it's initialized. I'm sure you know it but you use constants for values that should not be possible to change (by accident,..)

Answer (score 0):

No.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Basically the size of the value in memory (in java) is determined by the type.  Different primitives consume different amounts of memory.  This amount is constant for the given type of primitive.